# Unwanted twisting when using Nurbs path

Tags: curve-modifier

I'm making a loop for my driving game. I used a [`Path`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/primitives.html#path) curve and [`Array Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) to create it. For normal flat turns it works fine but for this track, I can't get it to not twist. I've tried setting the twist method to tangent but it results in some weird flipping of the track halfway. Z-up adds a 180 twist in the middle and minimum causes the entire track to twist.

[image: Tangent twist method]

[image: Z-up twist method]

[image: Minimum twist method]

Comment: Why don't you use a screw modifier, empty as the axis object, on a profile?

Answer (score 0):

While in curve's *Edit Mode*, enable *Normals* under *Overlays* so you can see the tilting of your path curve.

[image]

Then select a control point and press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the [`N-Panel`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html). Under the *Item* tab you can adjust the *Tilt*.

[image]